# Object.entries() doesn't work in specific place

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have very weird problem in my code, i used Object.entries 3 times to create an object with [key,value] and in the 4th time it doesn't work.

Code that works:

```
let arrayofSecondSixMonths = ["Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]; //Present second 6 Months of the year.
const monthsSecond = months.splice(0,6) //[100,200,300,400,500,600] for example

var lineArraySecondSix = {};
arrayofSecondSixMonths.forEach((key, i) => lineArraySecondSix[key] = monthsSecond[i]);

const lineDataSecondMonths = {... lineArraySecondSix}; //Fetch it to Graph.
const arrLineSecondMonth = new Array();
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(lineDataSecondMonths)) {
arrLineSecondMonth.push({x:key,y:value})
}
console.log("Outcome of Second months: ", arrLineSecondMonth);
```

Code that weirdly doesn't work:

```
let nextYearMonths = ["Jan 21","Feb 21","Mar 21","Apr 21","May 21","Jun 21"]; //Present first 6 Months of the year.
const futureIncome = resultIncome; //[348,53,1291,226,1306,424];

const result = {};
const barData = {...result};
 
nextYearMonths.forEach((key,i) => result[key] = futureIncome[i])
const arr4 = new Array();
for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(barData)) {
  arr4.push({x:key,y:value});
}
console.log("Arr 4 " , arr4);
```

Console log of arr4:

```
Arr 4  Array []
```

any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

The `result` is initially an empty object which gets spread into `barData` for some reason. Either assign to `barData` inside the loop instead, or drop `barData` entirely and only use the `result` object:

```js
let nextYearMonths = ["Jan 21", "Feb 21", "Mar 21", "Apr 21", "May 21", "Jun 21"]; //Present first 6 Months of the year.
const futureIncome = [348, 53, 1291, 226, 1306, 424];

const result = {};
const barData = { ...result };

nextYearMonths.forEach((key, i) => barData[key] = futureIncome[i])
const arr4 = new Array();
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(barData)) {
  arr4.push({
    x: key,
    y: value
  });
}
console.log("Arr 4 ", arr4);
```

or

```js
let nextYearMonths = ["Jan 21", "Feb 21", "Mar 21", "Apr 21", "May 21", "Jun 21"]; //Present first 6 Months of the year.
const futureIncome = [348, 53, 1291, 226, 1306, 424];

const result = {};

nextYearMonths.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = futureIncome[i])
const arr4 = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
  arr4.push({
    x: key,
    y: value
  });
}
console.log("Arr 4 ", arr4);
```

or avoid creating the object at all:

```js
let nextYearMonths = ["Jan 21", "Feb 21", "Mar 21", "Apr 21", "May 21", "Jun 21"]; //Present first 6 Months of the year.
const futureIncome = [348, 53, 1291, 226, 1306, 424];

const arr4 = nextYearMonths.map((key, i) => ({ x: key, y: futureIncome[i] }));
console.log("Arr 4 ", arr4);
```

Comment: Oh i get it, i misplaced const barData = {...result}; ... silly me, just tired and lost focus, thank you very much guys